# powershell InternetExplorer.Application Prompt box

Tags: javascript, html, powershell

I can not add any value to the pop-up window.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>PS Prompt test</h2>

<button onclick="Function()" id="test">send value</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function Function() {
    var txt;
    var text = prompt("Please enter text:", "example text");
    if (text == null || text == "") {
        txt = "User cancelled the prompt.";
    } else {
        txt = "Your text is: " + text;
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Below are the commands that helped me get to the pop-up window:

```
$ie = New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application;
$loginpage = "http://127.0.0.1/prompt.html"
$ie.Navigate2($loginpage)
$ie.Visible = $true;
While ($ie.Busy) {Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100}
$ie.document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementByID("test").click()
```

After they are executed, the script waits for actions
[image]

Please, help. How to enter any value and click the pop-up button?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you not enter any text into the input field where it states "example text"?

I've tested and the code works as expected - I am able to retrieve the input value by appending the following.

```
$result = $ie.document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementByID("demo").innerText
$result
```