# javascript window.prompt() auto click yes

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to automate a click in a javascript with window.prompt()

How to do this with javascript click "yes" automatically

Here is an example code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>PS Prompt test</h2>

<button onclick="Function()" id="test">send value</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function Function() {
    var txt;
    var text = prompt("Please enter text:", "example text");
    if (text == null || text == "") {
        txt = "User cancelled the prompt.";
    } else {
        txt = "Your text is: " + text;
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

---

### The script should replace the default value with a new one and click on the button

Thanks!

Comment: `prompt` will block your javascript. how do you want to automate it?

Comment: Doesn't this *entirely* defeat the purpose of using `prompt` in the first place?

Comment: need a script that will click on the button named "yes" on this page

Comment: `prompt` doesn't have `yes` button.

Comment: Why do you to automate a prompt? The prompt is designed to wait for user input.

Comment: this is necessary for the next task https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49571104/powershell-internetexplorer-application-prompt-box

Comment: someone wanna be hacker

Answer (score 1):

Not possible in a default browser, if you build your own interface with CefSharp you can overwrite default prompt behavior.

What you can do, but I do not recommend:

```
window.prompt = function(text, defaultText){ return defaultText; }
```

This way you will overwrite all prompt dialogs.

Answer (score 0):

When using prompt, JavaScript execution is halted at that point. There is no way to automate it. I don't see a reason to do so either as you can simply set the text directly?